# How to run a Python file on Ubuntu that requires root privileges

Tags: python, ubuntu, elevated-privileges

I just started experimenting with Python's keyboard module, and wanted to test out a few lines of code:

```
import keyboard
keyboard.write("Hello")
```

However, when I try to run the file from IDLE or from the terminal, there is an error message.

In IDLE: "You must be root to run this file from linux."

On `root` terminal: "Permission Denied."

Any suggestions on how to get this to run?

(Note: I have tried using other modules in various files and they worked fine, so I know my Python installation is fine). I am on Ubuntu 20.04.

Update:
I tried running the file using `sudo`, but I got the same error message: Permission Denied

Comment: Are you aware of `sudo`? `sudo script.py`? If this is foreign to you, I would recommend you brush up on your Linux/Unix basics before continuing.

Comment: What do you mean by "root terminal"? And are you sure that's the full error message? Normally you should get the name of the file too, like `test.py: Permission denied`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try sudo command like `sudo python3 script.py`.

if it's don't work you can try these things;

1. `chmod +x script.py`
2. `python3 script.py`

Comment: Why `python3 script.py`? You need to be root to use the `keyboard` module.

Comment: I am the root user, but it still won't run. Error message: Permission Denied

Comment: python3 or python command allows you to run your python file. If you use python2.x.x you can use python but if you use python3.x.x you can use python3 command

Comment: did you try chmod +x command? beacuse this problem seems like for your python file haven't enough permission

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the directory where the file saved.
Run following command by opening the terminal in that directory.

```
python3 file_name.py
```